# How to script SOAP based web service using SUDS python package

Tags: python

I wanted to use python for automating SOAP based web service using SUDS package. I'm facing problem in writing the script to get started off. Since, Web Services we use include multiple tags n complex structure could someone pls help in creating one for me. Below is the xml request of the web service.

XML Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mod="http://models.ws.common.abc.com" xmlns:ser="http://sa.models.ws.common.abc.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <mod:adtwsHeader>
         <adtwss>
            <userName>admin</userName>
            <password>password</password>
         </adtwss>
      </mod:adtwsHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:ServiceRequest>
         <subId>Test_DLT</subId>
      </ser:ServiceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I could just complete it till here
Script:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
#URL invocation
url = 'WDSL_URL'
client = Client(url)

#print client

result = client.service.retrieveService(subId='Test_DLT')
print result
```

Following is the output when I run the script
Test_DLT

It is printing the subid itself on the console. But actually it should retrieve service information from the db for the respective subid as response.
Our web services need authentication (username, password) to be provided in xml request. I was facing problem for coding that part using SUDS.This the part of header where we provide username and password:

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <mod:adtwsHeader>
         <adtwss>
            <userName>admin</userName>
            <password>password</password>
         </adtwss>
      </mod:adtwsHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Could someone please help me or provide me the SUDS code for the above piece of code.

Thanks for any help in advance.
-sasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[suds documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#CUSTOMSOAPHEADERS) has a short section on custom headers. I can't test it but something like this could work:

```
from suds.sax.element import Element

ns_mod = ('mod', 'http://models.ws.common.abc.com')

header = Element('adtwsHeader', ns=ns_mod)
container = Element('adtwss', parent=header)

username = Element('userName', parent=container)
username.setText('usernameGoesHere')

password = Element('password', parent=container)
password.setText('myPassword123')

client.set_options(soapheaders=header)
```

Comment: Thank you eclaird. I have tweaked it little later it worked. Thank you so much.